# How to work with Microstation DGN v8i files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms, dgn

I have a set of multiple files in DGN format (Microstation V8i). I would like to work with them in Qgis.

Since QGIS only support pre-V8i dgn files, I cannot directly open the files.
My first idea was to find a way to publish DGN files on a WMS service and then import it in QGIS.

Do you know any software that will allow me to publish dgn files in WMS ?
Is there a better way to work with dgn files in QGIS?

A little precision : it is not a one time work that I want to do : people work all the times on these dgn files and I need to open them in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Far as i know, there is no Open Source solutions for v8 dgn, only way is to convert to another file format. There may be some Bentley products which do it , but I'm not familiar with them. 
Far as i know , there is no tool in "base" Microstation SELECT 8i to create raster from CAD-file.

Solutions for file conversion : Microstation and save to some supported file format .  FME  commercial, very good tool. AutoCAD supports load and save

Comment: There is Bentley Geo Web Publisher V8i which can publish it via WMS but I wanted to know if there was something else to do the job.

Comment: in v8i you can save as dxf, use the dxf in QGIS.

Answer (score -3):

First use global mapper and save as a shape file than u will open in qgis with all vector information like

In Ms. Save dgn then
Open.in global mapper 
After that in global mapper export in vector file
And then save as shape file now u can open in qgis with all info.like as a road building etc.